# Modifying UIVIew above GLKView causing crashes

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkview

I have random crashes in my application. Eventually i figured out that the crashes happen when i add UIVIew elements and modify their center position. The crashes don't happen on IPad Air 2 but the scenario is consistent on IPad Air - when the UIViews are on, there are crashes and the crashes disappear when the views are removed. The crashes happens asynchronously with the following stack:

```
#0  0x0000000190bf1f28 in gpus_ReturnGuiltyForHardwareRestart ()
#1  0x0000000190bf2ec4 in gpusSubmitDataBuffers ()
#2  0x0000000189d56254 in gliPresentViewES_Exec ()
#3  0x0000000189d5616c in gliPresentViewES ()
#4  0x0000000189d63cbc in -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] ()
#5  0x0000000101ff8078 in EAGLContext_presentRenderbuffer(EAGLContext*, objc_selector*, unsigned long) ()
#6  0x00000001877dc638 in -[GLKView _display:] ()
#7  0x000000018b55eeb8 in CA::Layer::display() ()
#8  0x000000018b5413a0 in CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#9  0x000000018b54108c in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#10 0x000000018b54071c in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#11 0x000000018b540470 in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#12 0x000000018b539c10 in CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) ()
#13 0x000000018666f3f8 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#14 0x000000018666d19c in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#15 0x000000018666d5cc in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#16 0x000000018659d280 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#17 0x00000001915500cc in GSEventRunModal ()
#18 0x000000018bd8adf8 in UIApplicationMain ()
#19 0x000000010077d36c in main at /Code/splinedr/Splinedr/main.mm:18
#20 0x000000019b7fa8b8 in start ()
```

I render OpenGL using calls to `[self.view needDisplay]` and modify UIViews right before that.

How should i deal with this issue?

Comment: Do the crashes happen only at the moment when the UIIMageViews are added? How is the GLKView being refreshed? Are you calling display directly? If so have you set the enableSetNeedsDisplay to 0?

Comment: I edited my question and added more info

Comment: Did you set your GLKView's paused property to 0?

Comment: Yes - but i do call needDisplay many times in a short time because the view changes (users if changing the view angle)

Comment: Does it happen at the moment the UIImageViews are added?

Comment: No - the crash is totally asynchronous. And it can be any UIView and not only UIImageView. Tried also simple UIViews with colored background - crashes if there were there and never crashed if i did not add them

Comment: Are you calling setNeedsDisplay or display?

Comment: I am calling [self.view setNeedsDisplay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your GLKViewController is paused, and that the GLKView's enableSetNeedsDisplay is set to 1. If those are already set correctly, it might be that you are calling setNeedsDisplay on a background thread, and that your subviews are triggering conflicting calls on the main thread. Make sure all of your calls to setNeedsDisplay are called from the main thread. One easy way to verify is to just put a print statement next to each call.

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
printf("%s\n",dispatch_queue_get_label(DISPATCH_CURRENT_QUEUE_LABEL));
```

Another alternative is to set enableSetNeedsDisplay to zero and just call [self.view display] directly. You might have to add a couple of display calls here and there when views appear and frames change, but it ultimately will give you more control. If it doesn't solve the problem entirely, it will at least make it easier to follow the stack trace as all draw calls will originate from one of your calls to display.

Comment: This was my first guess. setNeedsDisplay is called only on main thread

Answer (score 0):

Apple says that an exception indictates some background misuse and strongly recommands that apps entering the background pausing or stopping using OpenGL ES.

[Apple Documentation for Implementing a Multitasking-Aware OpenGL ES App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH5-SW1)